# Broadcast Receiver onReceive() not work

Tags: java, android

events onRecive in Class Broadcast Receiver not work
In manifest all ok, but I don't see Log info in android Monitor. How can i solve this problem? I check this problem by calling to my phone
i use Xiaomi Redmi3s

Class CallReciver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("tesat", "test");
    }
}
```

Mainfest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="org.koshalogik.showcaller">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/belarus"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            </activity>

            <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
<activity
                android:name=".ContentActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Your log message is set to log verbose, which means it will only show up if your monitor settings are tweaked to show verbose messages. If you haven't done this, try using `Log.i()` instead.

Comment: In order to register a `BroadcastReceiver` your app has to be started first. How are you starting it without `ACTION_MAIN` intent filter on your `MainActivity` ?

Comment: @JoeyHarwood change, but dont see

Comment: @LordRaydenMK i remove Activity with ACTION_MAIN, because stackoverflow write fo me, that is many code

Comment: It should work. Either you aren't getting permission to read state or you aren't testing it on the right use case. These are the two reason for not getting log.

Comment: try setting priority to.. `<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">

Comment: READ_PHONE_STATE is a dangerous permission. Did you request for it and enable it at run-time?

Comment: add permision in my phone - all OK

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="org.koshalogik.showcaller">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/belarus"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            </activity>

            <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

<activity
                android:name=".ContentActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```